# How to use a blob URL as an image source in Chrome's Global Media Controls?

Tags: javascript, mediasession

I'm trying to customize the display in Chrome's Global Media Controls. So I used `navigator.mediaSession.metadata` to set the title and other things and it works.
But I also want to set the background image, like in the example below:
[image]

I tried using the following code:

```
  navigator.mediaSession.metadata.artwork = [{sizes, src, type}];
```

But `src` is a blob URL, like this: `blob:http://localhost:3000/8afe91b0-4689-4f6b-9984-21aedc834253`

I know this blob URL is OK since I can use it in as an `<img>` source and it's correctly displayed.

I also tried to fetch the blob itself and using `URL.createObjectURL()` but this gives me another (valid) blob URL and it doesn't work any better.

Final note: I think the way I set the `artwork` property is correct because if I use a "regular" image URL, it works.

**EDIT 1:**
I've just discovered that while it's not working in the control view activated via the [image] button, the image appears correctly when I use my keyboard media keys:
[image]

**EDIT 2:**
Another discovery: it works (i.e. using a blob URL as `src`) with JPG images but not with PNG images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using JPG images which work just fine.

So, my conclusion is: you can use a blob URL as an artwork source, as follows:

```
navigator.mediaSession.metadata.artwork = [
    {
        sizes: '150x200',
        src: 'blob:https://blablabla.com/4065a1d2-a23b-4cff-8ccd-3c6bce6e3b55',
        type: 'image/jpeg'
    }
];
```

My other conclusion is that there's a bug with PNG images (see **EDIT 1** in my question).